# Why does openssl work only with internal IP?

Tags: ssl, iptables, ip, tcp, openssl

I want to debug a SSL connection, so I followed the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203562/openssl-s-client-cert-proving-a-client-certificate-was-sent-to-the-server) question and wanted to run the first test:

```
# openssl s_client -connect SERVER_IP:PORT -state -debug
```

and got the following output:

```
socket: Connection refused
connect:errno=111
```

I looked it up and found out that it has nothing to do with SSL, it means that either the server isn't running or the port is blocked by the firewall. I logged to the server and checked that in fact it is running and that the PORT is open for listening for all IP addresses:

```
# netstat -plan | grep PORT
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:PORT               0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      PID/java
```

Here is the funny part: when I used the internal IP of my server to run the above openssl command, I got the expected output.

The behavior is the same regardless if I try to connect to the server from the client or from the server itself.

I added the port to the iptables. Here is how they look like now:

```
# iptables -L -v | grep PORT
40  4252 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:PORT
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:PORT
```

Why am I unable to connect with the server using the external IP, but it works with the internal IP?

**Edit:** all my `iptables` rules have the `ACCEPT` keyword- the command `iptables -L -v | grep REJECT` gives no output.

Comment: The most common mistake for novice firewall administrators is that they add a new rule and then discover that it won't take effect. The reason for that is that the `-A` option **appends** that new rule, **after all existing rules** . Please remember that firewall rules are checked in the order they are listed. The kernel will stop processing the chain when the first rule is triggered that will either allow or dis-allow a packet or connection and the new rule may never be reached. So please consider (posting) your complete firewall (with `[sudo] iptables -L -v -n` ) rather the individual rules.

Comment: @HBruijn,unfortunately, I can't post the complete firewall-it's a company system. Could you tell me what to look for? How can I have a rule that works for the internal IP address, but not for the external one?

Comment: The typical problem is a rule that blocks all traffic `iptables -A INPUT  -j REJECT` after which you add a rule opening a new post `iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Thank you. I'll check that. But do you have any idea why a rule would allow traffic via an internal IP address and block traffic via an external IP address?

Comment: Does the server actually own the external address to which you refer, or is it behind some kind of NAT that maps an external address onto the server's internal address?